# Android change activity which extends mainactivity layout

Tags: android, android-layout, inheritance, android-activity, extends

I have activities that extends MainActivity and here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private DrawerLayout dw;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle barToggle;
    private Toolbar toolBar;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setActivityView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
        setSupportActionBar(this.toolBar);
        this.dw = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        this.barToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dw, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);
        dw.addDrawerListener(barToggle);
        barToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        this.navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        this.navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        setActionBarTitle("Home");
    }

    public void setActivityView(int view){
        setContentView(view);
    }
    public void setActionBarTitle(String title){
        this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (barToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item
        return true;
    }
```

and here is my reminder activity which extends MainActivity

```
public class ReminderActivity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder);
        setActionBarTitle("Reminder");
        //setActivityView(R.layout.activity_reminder);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onNavigationItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        super.setActionBarTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void setActivityView(int view) {
        super.setActivityView(view);
    }
```

My problem is about ReminderActivity s layout when I try to change its layout I get app crashed error. If I don't, everything is fine. The problem is about inheritance, using the base onCreate, I think.

Debug log:

```
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068): Process: com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent, PID: 12068
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent.ReminderActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.DrawerLayout
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.DrawerLayout
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.DrawerLayout
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.DrawerLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent.MainActivity.setActivityView(MainActivity.java:47)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent.ReminderActivity.setActivityView(ReminderActivity.java:38)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at com.activityagent.tayfunakguc.activityagent.ReminderActivity.onCreate(ReminderActivity.java:19)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
09-06 08:12:05.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
09-06 08:12:05.231: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
09-06 08:12:05.231: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
09-06 08:12:05.231: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
09-06 08:12:05.231: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-06 08:12:05.231: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-06 08:12:05.231: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
09-06 08:12:05.231: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-06 08:12:05.231: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
09-06 08:12:05.231: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Please post the logs

Comment: Please add log here

Comment: Do you have a purpose for extending `MainActivity`. Or do you want to call  `ReminderActivity` from `MainActivity`?

Comment: sorry it s about xml file  i fixed the tag like android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout sorry for bothering

Comment: If you want to integrate Navigation drawer with Activity,then better way is to integrate Navigation drawer with BaseActivity and not with child activity.

Comment: You fixed the problem or still facing ?

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks